# Angular Interceptor read response header

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-http-interceptors

I have an interceptor on my angular app, I need to see the response header after the request is completed, currently, I'm doing this

```
return next.handle(copy).do((event: any) => {
        if (event && event.headers && event.headers.get('x-token')) {
            console.log('\ndelaying', event.headers.get('x-token'));
            const authService = this.authService;
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log('\ndelayed', event.headers.get('x-token'));
                const token = event.headers.get('x-token');
                authService.setJWT(token);
            }, 1000 * 3); // delay

        }

    }, error => {
        if (error && error.status === 401) {
            this.authService.logout();
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
        }
    });
}
```

after the response is received I'm checking headers. if the x-token is sent from the server I'm renewing my app's JWT by replacing it with the new one I received

now this is the middleware i have on my REST API Server

```
module.exports = {
refreshToken: (req, res, next) => {
    let reQtoken = req.get('authorization') ? req.get('authorization') : req.query.token;
    verifyJWT(reQtoken)
        .then((decodedToken) => {
            //var current_time = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
            const tokenDate = moment.unix(decodedToken.iat);
            const diff = moment().diff(tokenDate, 'minutes');
            console.log('\n',reQtoken);
            console.log(tokenDate,diff, moment());
            if (diff > 3) {
                console.log('here');
                const token = createJWTToken({
                    username: decodedToken.username,
                    person_id: decodedToken.person_id
                });
                res.set({
                    'x-token': token,
                    'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'x-token'
                });
            }
            next()
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .json({
                    message: "Invalid auth token provided.",
                    err: err
                })
        });
}
};
```

i may be doing something stupid but i am not able to figure out. please see the log from angular app below

[image]

the response always has a JWT even my server is not sending it because it only sends when the time difference between the JWT created and the current time is more than 3 minutes, so maybe it is caching or I'm getting it in a wrong way because in the log sometime the JWT is when i created it hours ago, please suggest a solution

Comment: any reason why you are using that `setTimeout`?

Comment: i was just testing trying to delay it for few seconds